# Can I get a warning when promoting an int to a long?

Tags: c#

In the C# compiler, does anyone know of a warning that can be generated when passing an int to a long?
In my project this would tell me of something that needs changing to long in my code.
I have checked SonarLint and Rosylynator and they don't have any options on the face of it.

I am converting a transaction table to have a long PK instead of an int PK. This is a massive codebase and there are situations where a related table hasn't been converted and therefore it passes int into a converted function call that takes longs. So it would highlight the need to convert a property/column in another table. I'm not sure I would leave that warning turned on all the time for sure.

Comment: I doubt there's anything built-in. You could write an analyzer reasonably easily, I think

Comment: *"something that needs changing to long"* - can you give an example? I believe it's XY problem.

Comment: If you're code is working with something as an `int`, and it's not inappropriately casting a `long` into that `int` in the first place, it's difficult to see why your code would *need* changing if something else wants to receive it as an `long`. It's an implicit conversion *because* you don't lose any values in the conversion.

Comment: I like the idea of writing an analyzer. That would be useful on this project.

Comment: Okay, but I don't know what good it will do: "Warning! Be careful when promoting an int to a long!" :)